# Unity 2D can't figure out how to get input for the key "E"

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am creating a 2D Unity game but I've come across an issue that confuses me, I can't seem to find out how to Get Input for the key "E" for context I'm trying to make a system where when the player is standing over the shop and presses "E" they enter the shop and can buy things

(the first if statement is to change the shop to a highlighted colour to make it clear so ignore that, ShopSR is just the variable for the shops sprite renderer, also for now instead of being able to enter the shop I've just used print as a placeholder)

Code:

```
 private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
    {
        if(other.CompareTag("Shop"))
        {
            ShopSR.sprite = ShopHighlighted;
        }

        if (other.CompareTag("Shop") && Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.E))
        {
            print("ENTER SHOP");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You will not be able to press the E key at lightning speed when entering the trigger, of course you can somehow manage to press it, but this is most likely for hardcore players. If you want to use inputs then you need to update it every frame:

```
  //Called one frame when the trigger is entered
  private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
        {
            if(other.CompareTag("Shop"))
            {
                ShopSR.sprite = ShopHighlighted;
            }    
        }
  //Called every time an object is in a trigger
  private void OnTriggerStay2D(Collider2D other)
        {
    
            if (other.CompareTag("Shop") && Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.E))
            {
                print("ENTER SHOP");
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```cs
    bool isOnShop;

    void Update(){
        if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.E) && isOnShop)
            // User is on shop, do your code
    }

    private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
    {
        if(other.CompareTag("Shop"))
        {
            ShopSR.sprite = ShopHighlighted;
            isOnShop = true;
        }
    }

    private void OnTriggerExit2D(Collider2D other){
        isOnShop = false;
    }
```

Or follow the suggestion above with OnTriggerStay2D